# git log range returning commits even before the date branch was created

Tags: git

I executed cmd, which return nothing

```
$ git log --author-date-order master..Feature/my-branch src/path/file.json
```

but if I execute

```
$ git log --author-date-order origin/master..Feature/my-branch src/path/file.json
```

its returning me commits even before the branch was created,

```
commit 638e9f5dadfb0e3d088970d9163db9e3179d819e
Merge: 6a30a07d6 cc8eb36a4
Author: author name
Date:   Fri Feb 18 12:10:02 2022 +0500

    Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/company/repo

commit 6a30a07d69c831a12dcaeaf48ca8804942073f8a
Merge: 61e846453 5b7c54184
Author: author name
Date:   Tue Feb 15 18:08:38 2022 +0500

    Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/company/repo

commit 61e8464537504de05712b61dcf4ce5f141309632
Merge: f1f55030c 138388f26
Author: author name
Date:   Fri Oct 11 16:37:56 2019 +0200

    Merge pull request #854 from comp/development

    19.1.16.0 to master
```

where as the branch was created from master on Feb 24

I need to execute it with origin/master as its requirement for github action.

Comment: It looks like your `origin/master` and `master` branches don't have the same commits. Have you run `git remote update`?

Comment: I clone a fresh repo now its showing same output, but why its showing older commits? The range .. cmd should only show commits after branch created.

Comment: ` The range .. cmd should only show commits after branch created. ` - not exactly. It should show commits that is on the second branch, but not on the first branch. So it could be that the first branch is outdated. Could you check the output of `git log --author-date-order origin/master..master` to see if `origin/master` and `master` differs?